# I need to know how to double code, but not by multiplying it, but by literally writing a function to double a list

Tags: javascript

I need help to double a list, by doing this.

10,10,20,20,30,30,40,40

I need a function that will have the above happen by having the number made in an array twice.

This is what I've tried:

```
function doubleList(){
    var i, s,
        myStringArray = [ "Hello", "World" ], 
        len = myStringArray.length; 

    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) { 
        if (i in myStringArray) {
            s = myStringArray[i]; 
        }
    }
```

It's not giving me the expected results because the code can't loop the numbers I need, I tried just simply going i < 2 and doubling it, but that didn't work at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: What will be your input? [10, 20, 30, 40] ?

Comment: It would be as such.

Comment: The way of asking questions is: tell your inputs, tell what you expect from your outputs, then show what you have already tried, and tell us why the code you've written yourself doesn't meet your expectations.

Comment: I would need for it to double any available number such as above/

Comment: function doubleList(){
var i, s, myStringArray = [ "Hello", "World" ], len = myStringArray.length;
for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
  if (i in myStringArray) {
    s = myStringArray[i];
}

Comment: Above is my code, I need a way for it to loop without it being so messy, and with it to actually work by repeating number characters.

Comment: My inputs would be any random number characters, and I need it to have a way to repeat said number characters.

Comment: Like 1,1 or 2,2/

Comment: You can edit your question to add the code, I just edited your question to add it. It's still missing your explanation of why it's not giving you the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```js
console.log([].concat.apply([], [10, 20, 30, 40].map(x => [x, x])))
```

Another way:

```js
const list = [10, 20, 30, 40]

const doubleList = (list) => {
  const res = []
  for (let x of list) {
    res.push(x)
    res.push(x)
  }
  return res
}
console.log(doubleList(list))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function doubleArrayElems(array) {
  let arrayLen = array.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLen; i += 2) {
    array.splice(i, 0, array[i]);
  }
}

let arrayElem = document.getElementById('array');
let doubleArrayElem = document.getElementById('double-array');

var myArray = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
arrayElem.innerHTML = myArray.toString();

doubleArrayElems(myArray);

doubleArrayElem.innerHTML = myArray.toString();
```

```html
Array: <p id="array"></p>
Doubled Array: <p id="double-array"></p>
```

Yes, but without the extras at the end with just 40 and 50

Comment: `Yes, but without the extras at the end with just 40 and 50` ??? no idea what you mean

Comment: The code snippet when run shows me just doubled versions of the first three.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array#forEach` to loop over it and push the element twice into a new array

```js
function doubleArray(x) {
  var tempArray = [];
  x.forEach(function(item) {
    tempArray.push(item);
    tempArray.push(item)
  })

  return tempArray;
}
var m = [10, 20, 30, 40];

console.log(doubleArray(m))
```